# what PAE score in AlphaFold can be considered a good prediction

Tags: bioinformatics

According to the FAQs on [AlphaFold homepage](https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/):

For a protein of length num_res, the JSON file has the following structure of arrays format:

```
[
    {
        "predicted_aligned_error": [[0, 1, 4, 7, 9, ...], ...], # Shape: (num_res, num_res).
        "max_predicted_aligned_error": 31.75
    }
]
```

The fields in the JSON file are:

- predicted_aligned_error: The PAE value of the residue pair, rounded to the closest integer. For the PAE value at position (i, j), i is the residue on which the structure is aligned, j is the residue on which the error is predicted.
- max_predicted_aligned_error: A number that denotes the maximum possible value of PAE. The smallest possible value of PAE is 0.

I'd like to obtain AlphaFold predicted structure searched by uniprot accession ID. Using the AlphaFold API and entering a uniprot accessionID, I'm able to get structures and this predicted aligned error json file. My question is how do I measure the max PAE. Since its range is [0, inf], I'm wondering what value I should use as a cut-off for a good/bad prediction. Is there any distributions of max PAE across all archived predictions that I could use as a reference for making a cut-off value?

Eventually I just want to have some credible protein structures predicted and filter out low accuracy predictions for further research.

Thank you all for help!!

Comment: Voting to close as this is more about interpreting bioinformatic outputs than programming. Instead, consider posting on [Bioinformatics SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com) where it is more likely domain experts will answer.